# How to handle with GitFlow and Subtasks

Tags: git, version-control

As a JIRA and GitFlow user, I'm experiencing some issues I'd like to know how to solve them.

With Jira, you can have several kind of Issues(https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/What+is+an+Issue) to solve.

If you've to perform a:

- **LinealTask**, it's easy to find out that you've to create a **new Feature** with GitFlow. And when you're done with it, **finish the feature**.
- **Task**, task is normally something "bigger" in terms of difficulty and time expending. So to handle better and optimize resources, the best idea is to split the task in subtasks (https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Creating+a+Sub-Task). However, what I am doing ATM is creating a **new feature** for every **subtask**. And as soon as I've finished a **subtask**, I **finish the feature**. However, I'm sure this is wrong. A feature should be finished when something is "totally" finished. And a subtask, is just a part of a Feature. Also note that when a **feature** is finished, it's merged to the main branch.

So my question is about what I previously mentioned above.

How should I use git-flow for SubTasks? Is there any way to create a Feature with Sub-Features?

Note that to handle all those branches changes and modifications, I'm using SourceTree.

I've thought about creating a new branch for every Task and then features for this branch, but that's not good, because branches should be something more global, and not task-specific; like "Develop", "Master", etc.

Any tips or questions are welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JIRA uses a git-flow derived from git-flow nvie which does not support creating features from branches other than develop.

JIRA would have to implement [git-flow AVH Edition](https://github.com/petervanderdoes/gitflow) in order to create a feature from any branch.

disclaimer: I'm the maintainer of git-flow AVH Edition.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So basically, the answer is that it's not possible with GitFlow. I'll have to keep working like I do, as I am not able to change to other git control system.

Comment: Well it's not possible with JIRA.